# complex query with joins, how to retrieve COUNTs

Tags: mysql, join, count, group-by, subquery

I have a rather complex query to retrieve products & attributes from several tables.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
    p.*,
    product_shop.*,
    product_shop.id_category_default,
    pl.*,  
    pbn.*,
    MAX(image_shop.id_image) id_image,
    il.legend, 
    m.name manufacturer_name,
    0 as quantity
FROM ps_category_product cp
LEFT JOIN ps_category c ON (c.id_category = cp.id_category)
LEFT JOIN ps_product p ON p.id_product = cp.id_product
INNER JOIN ps_product_shop product_shop ON (product_shop.id_product = p.id_product AND product_shop.id_shop = 1)
LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang pl ON (pl.id_product = p.id_product AND pl.id_shop = 1  AND pl.id_lang = 7)

## ########### Added joins ###########
LEFT JOIN ps_product_base_names pbn ON pbn.id_product = p.id_product
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT base_name, MAX(id_product) AS Max_ID_product 
    FROM ps_product_base_names 
    WHERE id_product IN (568110,568129,568134,568135,568136,568137,568139,568140,568141,602911,612411,612413,612512,612513,612515,612612,612616,616213,616217)
    GROUP BY base_name) groupedpbn 
ON (pbn.base_name = groupedpbn.base_name AND pbn.id_product = groupedpbn.Max_ID_product)
## ########### End added ###########

LEFT JOIN ps_image i  ON (i.id_product = p.id_product) LEFT JOIN ps_image_shop image_shop ON (image_shop.id_image = i.id_image AND image_shop.id_shop = 1 AND image_shop.cover=1)
LEFT JOIN ps_image_lang il ON (image_shop.id_image = il.id_image AND il.id_lang = 7)
LEFT JOIN ps_manufacturer m ON (m.id_manufacturer = p.id_manufacturer)
WHERE product_shop.active = 1 AND product_shop.visibility IN ("both", "catalog")
AND c.nleft >= 3 AND c.nright <= 4
AND c.active = 1
AND p.id_product IN (568110,568129,568134,568135,568136,568137,568139,568140,568141,602911,612411,612413,612512,612513,612515,612612,612616,616213,616217)
GROUP BY product_shop.id_product
ORDER BY pl.name asc LIMIT 0,30
```

I have added 2 JOINs (see comment) to retrieve products by their base name and get only 1 result per base name, to show in the main catalog overview page.

This all works fine, but now I would like to get the number of products that have been grouped per base name. Something like:

```
COUNT(id_product) AS product_variations
```

So let's suppose that the products with id_product 568110, 602911 & 612413 all have the same base name, the above query will return id_product 612413 as the result.

But how do I get the number of ID's that have been aggregated (3 for the product with id_product 612413) for every product in the result list?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here: https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/use-subqueries-to-count-distinct-50x-faster.html

My working query now looks like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
    p.*,
    product_shop.*,
    product_shop.id_category_default,
    pl.*,  
    pbn.*,
    cnt.product_variations, ## This line was added for the COUNT specified in the JOIN (see below)
    MAX(image_shop.id_image) id_image,
    il.legend, 
    m.name manufacturer_name,
    0 as quantity
FROM ps_category_product cp
LEFT JOIN ps_category c ON (c.id_category = cp.id_category)
LEFT JOIN ps_product p ON p.id_product = cp.id_product
INNER JOIN ps_product_shop product_shop ON (product_shop.id_product = p.id_product AND product_shop.id_shop = 1)
LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang pl ON (pl.id_product = p.id_product AND pl.id_shop = 1  AND pl.id_lang = 7)

## ########### Added joins ###########
LEFT JOIN ps_product_base_names pbn ON pbn.id_product = p.id_product
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT base_name, MAX(id_product) AS Max_ID_product 
    FROM ps_product_base_names 
    WHERE id_product IN (568110,568129,568134,568135,568136,568137,568139,568140,568141,602911,612411,612413,612512,612513,612515,612612,612616,616213,616217)
    GROUP BY base_name) groupedpbn 
ON (pbn.base_name = groupedpbn.base_name AND pbn.id_product = groupedpbn.Max_ID_product)

## This JOIN was added to COUNT aggregated product IDs
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT base_name, COUNT(id_product) AS product_variations 
    FROM ps_product_base_names 
    WHERE id_product IN (568110,568129,568134,568135,568136,568137,568139,568140,568141,602911,612411,612413,612512,612513,612515,612612,612616,616213,616217)
    GROUP BY base_name) cnt 
ON (pbn.base_name = cnt.base_name)
## ########### End added ###########

LEFT JOIN ps_image i  ON (i.id_product = p.id_product) LEFT JOIN ps_image_shop image_shop ON (image_shop.id_image = i.id_image AND image_shop.id_shop = 1 AND image_shop.cover=1)
LEFT JOIN ps_image_lang il ON (image_shop.id_image = il.id_image AND il.id_lang = 7)
LEFT JOIN ps_manufacturer m ON (m.id_manufacturer = p.id_manufacturer)
WHERE product_shop.active = 1 AND product_shop.visibility IN ("both", "catalog")
AND c.nleft >= 3 AND c.nright <= 4
AND c.active = 1
AND p.id_product IN (568110,568129,568134,568135,568136,568137,568139,568140,568141,602911,612411,612413,612512,612513,612515,612612,612616,616213,616217)
GROUP BY product_shop.id_product
ORDER BY pl.name asc LIMIT 0,30
```

To be honest, it works and it seems fast enough in my test environment, but I haven't got a clue if this solution is efficient or not. So any comments to possibly improve on my solution are still welcome.

Thanks, Mattie